# Include captcha code in form validation

Tags: javascript, captcha

How do you integrate this code into a validation condition in the form:

```
$("form").clientSideCaptcha({
            input: "#captchaText", 
            display: "#captcha",
            pass : function() { alert("Passed!"); return false; },
            fail : function() { alert("Please enter the text shown below");
    document.contactForm.textcaptcha.focus();
    return false; }
        });
```

Comment: when the form is submitted run the function and return true on pass/false on fail

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#form").submit(function(event) {
    //check for validCaptcha
    var validCaptcha = $("#form").clientSideCaptcha({
      input: "#captchaText",
      display: "#captcha",
      pass: function() {
        return true;
      },
      fail: function() {
        document.contactForm.textcaptcha.focus();
        return false;
      }
    });
    //invalid captcha - stop form submission
    if (!validCaptcha) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. 
The form already validates other form fields. Do I move the invalid captcha condition inside the current conditions?

Comment: you could add it as part of the existing validation yes, I would recommend moving the clientSideCaptcha method inside of a function and just calling `var validCaptcha = isCaptchaValid($('#form'));`  e.g `function isCaptchaValid(element){ return element.clientSideCaptcha({ //code }); }` to keep your validation code clean and readable

Comment: it seems this library actually binds to your form submit, an easy way to hack this would be to leave it as it is, and change validate function to `function validate(isValidCaptcha)` on the cliensideCaptcha: `,pass: validate(true), fail: validate(false)})`, then just return false if `!isValidCaptcha` at the top of the function and show an error message in the relevant field

Comment: I think I'm doing something wrong because I get alerts for the first name and the captcha field validation as the page loads. 
[link](http://berkeleycollege.edu/projects/1452_jt/test_rsvp.htm)

Comment: try this https://jsbin.com/mocugawoku/1/edit?html,js,console,output sorry for the mess seems there is no tidy button

Comment: It's looping the alert even if the captcha is correct. [link](http://berkeleycollege.edu/projects/1452_jt/test_rsvp4.htm)